# how can i set nginx to keep ask authentication everytime

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

i want to make a website with nginx for myself for fun and i was trying to add authentication to it. i added a user in /etc/nginx/.htpasswd. but its only one time asking me to type the password and when i refresh the page its not asking me again.here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file.

```
        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            auth_basic "Restricted Content";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

Comment: If you are protecting the entire site, the `auth` directives should be placed in the `server` block. But, your browser will cache the credentials, so you shouldn't necessarily need to enter the password on each visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure that is possibile, or at least, not natively.
HTTP authentication information is stored on your browser cache, and should only be requested again if the authentication fails or it's from a different realm (in auth_basic "Restricted Content"; it's Restricted).

Comment: Yes. You are right, i didn't think about that.thanks anyway